# Setting integers inside array to a fixed length

Tags: python, arrays

I´m trying to generate an array with integers of a fixed length of 6, so that e.g. 1234 is displayed as `001234` and 12345 as `012345`.
I can get it to work for an integer using:

```
x = 12345
x = '{0:06d}'.format(x)
print(x)
>>> 012345
```

I tried the same method for an array, but it doesn`t seem to work, so how can I convert this method to array entries?

```
dummy_array = np.array([1234, 653932, 21394, 99999, 1289])
for i in range(len(dummy_array)
    dummy_array[i] = '{0:06d}'.format(dummy[i])

print(dummy_array[2]) #test
>>>21394
```

Do I need convert the array entries to strings first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set:

```
dummy_array = np.array([1234, 653932, 21394, 99999, 1289],dtype=object)
```

it allows the numpy array to contain integers and strings simultaneously, which was your problem. With this simple dtype argument your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
'%06d'%123

Answer (score 0):

You first need to change the type of your array:

```
dummy_array = dummy_array.astype(str)
```

And then you can pad your strings:

```
for i in range(len(dummy_array)):
    dummy_array[i] = dummy_array[i].rjust(6)
```

Result:

```
>>> dummy_array
array(['  1234', '653932', ' 21394', ' 99999', '  1289'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`'{0:06d}'.format(x)` returns a formatted str for a passed int already.

The numpy array's dtype was set to `int64` on instantiation, by automatically guessing the array type from passed values of the python list with [`1234, 653932, 21394, 99999, 1289]`.

As your code modifies the original array, it converts values back to `int64` when you pass a `str` to it.

You can ofc. set the overall type to object as in @Lucas D. Meier 's answer.

But you can also create a new numpy array of `str` from this transformation

```
dummy_array = np.array([1234, 653932, 21394, 99999, 1289])
res_array = np.array(['{0:06d}'.format(x) for x in dummy_array])
=> array(['001234', '653932', '021394', '099999', '001289'], dtype='<U6')
```